# how to generate checkbox using pdfbox api

Tags: api, checkbox, pdfbox

please help me to generate checkbox in pdfpage using PDFbox-api,please give some code to generate checkbox in pdf page.please help me.

Comment: I am able to bring the checkbox, see the code at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399953/pdfbox-checkbox-is-not-displayed-if-set-readonly. But still some issues - i.e. it goes disappear when focused.

Comment: Check answer at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32600369/5201008](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32600369/5201008)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343232/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-checkbox-and-make-it-always-visible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a border to a checkbox and make it always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343232/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-checkbox-and-make-it-always-visible)