# PDFBox - checkbox is not displayed if set readonly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am generating PDF using PDFBox, where I need to add a checkbox, which needs to be preset to checked and readonly. But some how it does not work.

Please find below code, which adds the checkbox on PDF:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSFloat;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDCheckbox;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String arg[])  throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        document.addPage(page);

        COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary();
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Fields"), new COSArray()); // Added this line for Tilman's comment
        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document, acroFormDict);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);


        float x = 10f;
        float y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();  
        float yOffset = 15f;
        float yCurrent = y - yOffset;  

        COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray rect = new COSArray();
        rect.add(new COSFloat(x));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(yCurrent));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(x+20));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(yCurrent-20));

        cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field Type
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("testChk"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/Helv 7 Tf 0 g"));

        PDCheckbox checkbox = new PDCheckbox(acroForm, cosDict);
//      checkbox.setReadonly(true);
//      checkbox.setFieldFlags(PDField.FLAG_READ_ONLY);
        checkbox.setValue("Yes");
//      checkbox.check();
        page.getAnnotations().add(checkbox.getWidget());                          
        acroForm.getFields().add(checkbox); // Added this line for Tilman's comment

        yCurrent = yCurrent - 20 - yOffset;

        File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\CheckBox\\CheckBoxSample1.pdf");
        System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        document.save(file);
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Now if you uncomment the line:

```
checkbox.setReadonly(true);
```

Or

```
checkbox.setFieldFlags(PDField.FLAG_READ_ONLY);
```

The checkbox will no more displayed (or may be there but value is unchecked).
I am using PDFBox 1.8.10

Behavior is similar in Adobe Reader 11 and Foxit.

Also if I generate the PDF without setting the box readonly, in Adobe, I see the checkbox displayed with value set, but when I bring focus on it using tab, it gets disappear. And again on focus out (I click somewhere else other than checkbox), it appears again.

It seems like I am missing a very small thing, but could not find out.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any checkbox anywhere, although I see where it should be. You're not adding the checkbox to the acroform. Could it be that you accidentally deleted the line while editing down some bigger code for the question?

Comment: Tilman, thanks for reply. I have updated question and added two lines with comment 'Added this line for Tilman's comment'. Hope I am doing correctly. Even after this change in code, I cannot find any change in behavior.

Comment: Sadly I still have the problem that I can never see it. What you could try, is to add acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), true); If it still doesn't work, ask in the user mailing list. If you go there, post your code and upload the resulting PDF somewhere (you can't attach it). https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/ Our acroform expert is there (but I'm not promising you anything).

Comment: No problem. Thank you for feedback though. I have placed question on mailing list. If you need to refer my PDF, it is at:  https://github.com/PatelVishalJ/PDFBoxSampleFile
Click on "Download ZIP" button, unzip the downloaded file, that will contain the generated PDF file.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion, old code had the line 'cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/Helv 7 Tf 0 g"));' in comment, because of that you were not able to see the checkbox. After uncommenting the line, checkbox will get displayed but issue will be there as mentioned in question - i.e. on focus or on readonly set, the checkbox will get disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give field appearance using PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary class. That will fix above issue.

Please check sample code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSFloat;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDGamma;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDCheckbox;

public class MyCheckBox {
    public static void main(String arg[])  throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDResources res = new PDResources();
        String fontName = res.addFont(font);
        String da = "/" + fontName + " 10 Tf 0 0.4 0 rg";


        COSDictionary acroFormDict = new COSDictionary(); 
        acroFormDict.setBoolean(COSName.getPDFName("NeedAppearances"), true);
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.FIELDS, new COSArray());
        acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString(da));

        PDAcroForm acroForm =  new PDAcroForm(document, acroFormDict);
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);


        float x = 10f;
        float y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();  
        float yOffset = 15f;
        float yCurrent = y - yOffset;  

        PDGamma colourBlack = new PDGamma();
        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = 
                new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
        fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(colourBlack);
        COSArray arr = new COSArray();
        arr.add(new COSFloat(227/255f));
        arr.add(new COSFloat(239/255f));
        arr.add(new COSFloat(1f));
        fieldAppearance.setBackground(new PDGamma(arr));

        COSDictionary cosDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray rect = new COSArray();
        rect.add(new COSFloat(x));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(yCurrent));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(x+20));
        rect.add(new COSFloat(yCurrent-20));

        cosDict.setItem(COSName.RECT, rect);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field Type
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.TU, new COSString("Test Checkbox with PDFBox"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("testChk"));
        cosDict.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/F0 10 Tf 0 0.4 0 rg"));
//        cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 49152);        //Radio Button Symbol
        cosDict.setInt(COSName.F, 4);
//        cosDict.setInt(COSName.FF, 16384);

        PDCheckbox checkbox = new PDCheckbox(acroForm, cosDict);
        checkbox.setFieldFlags(PDCheckbox.FLAG_READ_ONLY);
        checkbox.setValue("Yes");
//        checkbox.setValue("Off");

        checkbox.getWidget().setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

        page.getAnnotations().add(checkbox.getWidget());                          
        acroForm.getFields().add(checkbox); 

        yCurrent = yCurrent - 20 - yOffset;

        File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\CheckBoxSample.pdf");
        System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        document.save(file);
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is anyone else thinking to themselves... all this code for a checkbox?!?!

Comment: Is there any issue with this code, please let me know so that it can be corrected!!

Comment: Nirav - Sorry, not a criticism of the code... more of a commentary on pdfbox. Thanks for providing the example - it helped me with my problem.

Comment: Expecting with PDFBOX-2, coding will be reduced and acroform fields controls will be easy to create and manipulate at developer`s perspective :)